# How can I compile and run project from command line(Windows 7)?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, command-line, makefile

I have a project which has a makefile:

```
# a simple makefile

# Uncomment, if compression support is desired
#DCOMP=-DWITH_COMPRESSION
#ZLIB=-lz

#Compiler
CC=g++
# compiler switches
#CPPFLAGS=-g -I.
CPPFLAGS=-O -I.
CFLAGS=-O -I. $(DCOMP) 

#LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib
#libraries
LIBS= -lm $(ZLIB)

# Compilation rules
# target:source
%.o:%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
%.o:%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
# $@-target, $<-source

DNAME=f3dProjBasicNoComp12
PROGRAM=project

PROJ_OBJECTS= project.o f3d.o f3dGridLite.o

#the first (default)
all:$(PROGRAM)

project:$(PROJ_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(PROJ_OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGRAM) *.o  core* *.ppm

pack:
    make clean
    (cd .. && tar cvzf $(DNAME).tgz $(DNAME))
```

And I want to run it on Windows. The professor has said that I should compile it and run, but he did not tell me how can I do this on Windows. I have read that I should use nmake MakeFile, but than:

```
'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

To run the application, I should use somethink like `project -x somethink.obj`.
But because I cannot compile the makefile I cannot run the project.

Can you help me?

Comment: You do have a compiler (and particularly Visual Studio) installed?

Comment: Check out [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/). They can "emulate" a UNIX environment in Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your project is configured to use gcc/g++ (as in your example) then you should install [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/). After that you start the mingw shell, you go to your directory and type `make` (provided that you installed make when installing mingw) or `make -f <makefile name>`.

**NOTE:** The windows path for `c:\mydir1\mydir2` is in mingw `/c/mydir1/mydir2`. So you should reach your directory by typing `cd /c/mydir1/mydir2`.

If your project is configured to use Visual Studio (cl.exe compiler) you can:

1. Start Visual studio console
2. Start a cmd.exe prompt and after that run `"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"` (or your corresponding `vcvars32.bat`)

After you done this you go to your directory with `cd c:\mydir1\mydir2` and type `nmake` (the make equivalent from visual studio package) or `nmake /f <your makefile name>`.

If you're required other toolchain to compile then you should follow specific steps. I remember that for using Borland compiler you only need to set the path to the `bcc32` executable.

**LATER EDIT:**

In case the project uses unix specific procedure you should use [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) (as mentioned in comments).

Answer (score 2):

1) You have to have Visual Studio installed

2) You have to run Visual Studio command prompt (you will find it in the Microsoft Visual Studio Start menu entry once you have it installed) and invoke `nmake` from there.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to download minigw for windows with gcc. Take a look at:
http://www.mingw.org/

Comment: I see no reason for using MinGW unless absolutely neccessary.

Comment: well the makefile seems to be gnu specific for example `CC=g++` . If he doesn't want to edit the makefiles that he gets throughout his course then installing cygwin, minigw or msys is the simplest solution. Maybe not the most elegant but the one requiring the least effort.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, Because you don't have Visual Studio?

Comment: @Pacerier: VS Express. It's great, try it out.