# How to run a project from cmd? (Windows 7)

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin, mingw

I have a project which has a makefile:

```
# a simple makefile

# Uncomment, if compression support is desired
#DCOMP=-DWITH_COMPRESSION
#ZLIB=-lz

#Compiler
CC=g++
# compiler switches
#CPPFLAGS=-g -I.
CPPFLAGS=-O -I.
CFLAGS=-O -I. $(DCOMP) 

#LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib
#libraries
LIBS= -lm $(ZLIB)

# Compilation rules
# target:source
%.o:%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
%.o:%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
# $@-target, $<-source

DNAME=f3dProjBasicNoComp12
PROGRAM=project

PROJ_OBJECTS= project.o f3d.o f3dGridLite.o

#the first (default)
all:$(PROGRAM)

project:$(PROJ_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(PROJ_OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGRAM) *.o  core* *.ppm

pack:
    make clean
    (cd .. && tar cvzf $(DNAME).tgz $(DNAME))
```

I have installed both the cygwin and mingw, but I can not Compile the make file or run the project :( I always get error:
first:

```
C:\Users\Bladeszasza>C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe  -B C:\Users\Bladeszasza\Docu
ments\vvd\f3dProjBasicNoComp12\Makefile
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for `C:\Users\Bladeszasza\Documents\vvd\f3dProj
BasicNoComp12\Makefile'.


C:\Users\Bladeszasza>C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe  -B C:\Users\Bladeszasza\Docu
    ments\vvd\f3dProjBasicNoComp12\Makefile
C;\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make: invalid option --z
Usage : mingw32-make [option] [target] ...
Options:
```

So I need to run the project which is called project.cpp 
But I do not know What to do with it >(
please help me

thanks

Comment: Usage error you're seeing is from make & not from your project.

Comment: I understand that but why? I have posted the whole makefile I did not get it :(

Comment: Where have you posted the Makefile?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411972/how-can-i-compile-and-run-project-from-command-linewindows-7   here

Comment: Please update this post, also remove irrelevant data such as the usage () code from your project.cpp

Comment: ok but i do not understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make must be used like [this](http://www.digipedia.pl/man/doc/view/mingw32-make.1/):

```
make [ -f makefile ] [ options ] ... [ targets ] ...
```

`-B` is used to always build

```
-B, --always-make
    Unconditionally make all targets.
```

So when you enter:

```
mingw32-make.exe -B C:\Users\Bladeszasza\Documents\vvd\f3dProjBasicNoComp12\Makefile
```

- you don't specify a makefile, because there is no `-f`
- you have one option: `-B`
- and `C:\Users\Bladeszasza\Documents\vvd\f3dProjBasicNoComp12\Makefile` is the target.

What you need to do instead is this:

```
mingw32-make.exe -f C:\Users\Bladeszasza\Documents\vvd\f3dProjBasicNoComp12\Makefile -B all
```